# Interact with long-running bash script. Automatic inputs when certain outputs appears

Tags: bash, automation

`echo "yes\yes\oops" | program` doesn't work well for a long-running program.

I can think of redirect the output of `program` to a file, then use a loop to `grep` that file until certain output appears. But is there any better idea?

Comment: I had to do a bit of guesswork on what you were asking. If I got it wrong, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer/are stuck with bash, perhaps you are looking for [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)?

More on that here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583

Answer (score 1):

Write a Python, Perl, Ruby or script in another language to interact with the program. In Python you'd use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). In Perl you'd use [`popen()`](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlopentut-openshell.html). Read the program's stdout line-by-line and match against known prompts, replying with the desired response by writing to the program's stdin.

You *can* do the same in bash, but I personally prefer not to.